# How to a create single/global log file for multiple NUnit tests

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, serilog

I'm executing some tests in visual studio test explorer that write to a log-file (I'm using Serilog). At the moment each time my BaseTest executes `LoggingFactory.InitializeLoggingFactory()`it creates a new log file, so I have multiple logs for each test class. How do I call `LoggingFactory.InitializeLoggingFactory()` globally so that I can end up with 1 log-file for each execution of all the tests?

```cs
    abstract class BaseTest
    {
        protected static IWebDriver driver;
        protected static WebDriverWait wait;
        protected static Actions actions;
        protected static ExcelDataFactory excelDataFactory;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void startLogger()
        {
            LoggingFactory.InitializeLoggingFactory();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver = new Browser().ConfigureBrowser(MyProps.Default.Browser);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MyProps.Default.TimeOut));
            actions = new Actions(driver);

            excelDataFactory = new ExcelDataFactory();
            ScreenshotFactory.SetDriverForScreenshot(driver);
            ExceptionTracker.RemoveAllExceptions();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            ExceptionTracker.PrintAllExceptions();

            if (driver != null)
            {
                driver.Close(); // Close the chrome window
                driver.Quit(); // Close the console app that was used to kick off the chrome window
                driver.Dispose(); // Close the driver.exe
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: test explorer]

[image: logs]

Answer (score 1):

You used `[OneTimeSetUp]` within the fixture class, so the method executes once per fixture. The fact that it's in a base class doesn't make it run fewer times because the base class is a logical part of each fixture.

You need to create a SetUpFixture, a class marked with `[SetUpFixture]` and place the one-time setup method there. If you want the log to be initialized just once for the entire assembly, place the SetUpFixture class outside of any namespace.

One more thing... Do **not** inherit any TestFixtures from the SetUpFixture... it stands by itself.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, i'll try out what you said